# Columns in a "post"

Tags: posts

I understand that all of wordpress is structured around certain key "entities". Some of which are,

1. Pages
2. Posts
3. Comments

That list is by no means exhaustive because I know wordpress has few other key "entities"

Every wordpress site has a "homepage" and when I change any of the "theme" settings, it is this "homepage" that reflects those changes. For example I can configure the home page to have a "sidebar" + "content" + "sidebar" or any variation thereof.

What I would like to know is, if I can have my "posts" use columns as well. Because I would like each of my "posts" to open in a new page and present 3 columns to the person browsing the site. The first column having a list of bookmarks into different parts of a video that is being displayed in the second column. And I would like to use the third column to display some pictures.

I know my requirement is very specific. I am a very new to wordpress. Any help in this regards would be much helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files and try to get a handle on how WordPress templates work. Some of what you wrote makes me think you only have a partial understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same by designing the layout structure in Single.php template page.

In wordpress, by default single.php is the filename which will display the single post of your blog. You just need to create the design layout as you need in this page.